Is it ok to use official movie posters in a case study in my UX/UI portfolio?
I’m working on a movie ticket booking app as part of my UX/UI portfolio. I wonder if using official movie posters in the app’s design (e.g., as images for movies listed in the app) is illegal or could become an issue when showcasing my work. I’ve noticed many designers use movie posters in their portfolio projects, especially on platforms like Behance, but isn't it illegal?
Thanks in advance!
